# Hiding an element without using display:none or visibility:hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-pdf

I am trying to render a PDF with react-pdf. To be clear, I mean [this](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf) react-pdf library, not the other one. I want to include certain text in the PDF that will be used for indexing in the future, but I want for that text to be invisible (or nearly invisible). I will later detect this text with a Python script that reads in the text from the PDF.

My question is how to achieve this by styling the hiddenheader.

`<Text style={styles.hiddenheader}>###HIDDEN HEADER###</Text>`

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  hiddenheader: {
    visibility: 'hidden',
    color: 'red',
  }
});
```

... Does not work. The text is still colored red, so I know that the style is being applied, but the text is not hidden, it is clear as day.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  hiddenheader: {
    display: 'none',
    color: 'red',
  }
});
```

... Also does not work. The text is still colored red, so I know that the style is being applied, but all instances except for one are deleted, and that one bizarrely appears at the very top of the first page, clear as day.

I don't need a solution that completely removes the element from the rendered page (and that might prevent the element from ever appearing). I just need one that makes the text invisible to the naked eye.

Comment: Have you tried `opacity: 0;`?

Comment: What if you set the text color to the same color as the background?

Comment: Thanks @AibCodesDaily If you make that an answer I'll delete mine and select yours as the chosen answer. Andrew, your solution is a bit less flexible, because the background color could theoretically change and then that's one more thing to remember, but still a reasonable solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we want the text to remain in the PDF for indexing, setting `opacity: 0` will ensure the text remains in the PDF without actually removing it from the document.

```
  hiddenheader: {
    opacity: 0,
    fontSize: 0.1
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use your external custom css for hide any tag in react-pdf

```
<Text style={{ marginBottom: 5 }} className="hidden">
    Issued By:Electronics Sector Council Of India
</Text>
```

Comment: like tailwind etc

Comment: here is the className ="hidden" is use by the tailwind css and other things are react-pdf property